# Action Bar padding differences between devices

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an action bar defined in the following manner:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_refresh"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_shelves"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_shelves"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>

... more items ...

</menu>
```

This is the main activity layout:

```
<com.totalboox.android.views.BorderedLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dp" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/actionbar_back_color" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</com.totalboox.android.views.BorderedLinearLayout>
```

This is how it displays on Samsung Tab with os 3.2

[image]

And this is how it displays on Motorola Zoom with os 4:

[image]

As you can see, it displays correctly on the Samsung tab, but it's on the top instead of being in the center for the Motorola Zoom.
Is there anyway to make sure the icons are centered on both devices?

Comment: Since the action bar does not look like either of your screenshots by default, how have you modified the action bar to look as you have it? Have you tried reverting those changes, to see the behavior of your buttons on an unmodified action bar?

Comment: Your comment actually sent me in the right direction. The problem wasn't with the way I defined my ActionBar, but rather with the layout which the ActionBar was included in. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've continued my research, but I still have the problem. I've added the layout of the main activity.

Comment: Since we have no idea what `BorderedLinearLayout` is, or how you are using it, it will be difficult for anyone to help you. You might consider adding `ViewServer` to your project, then using Hierarchy View to see what's different: https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer